# Phpstorm 2.1.1 - how to integrate Rubymine cucumber feature editor support

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, rubymine, phpstorm

I tryed both - to find it in available plugins integrated registry and to download rubymine and find it there, but nothing like *cucmber* or *BDD*/*behaviour* found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cucumber support is available only in RubyMine and IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with Ruby plug-in installed. You can't get this feature for PhpStorm.

You can vote for [WI-6325](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-6325) if you want Behat support.